# Помочь паскаль.Ошибка в коде

Tags: pascal

Доброго времени суток друзья, решил сделать домашнюю работу, но не понимаю в чем ошибка

```
program Hello; // Pascal [fpc 3.0.4]
var x,y,f,d:Integer;
begin
writeln('x');
readln(x);
y:=0;
d:=0;
f:=1;
while d<=9 do
d:=d+1;
f:=f*x;
y:=y+f*sin(d*Pi)/5);
writeln('y=',y:5:2);
readln;
end.
end.
```

Comment: да, а в чём, собственно ошибка?)

Comment: не компилируется в паскале

Comment: Разве цикл не начинается с begin? Ещё,  что за закрывающаяся скобка в y:=y+f*sin(d*Pi)/5);

Answer (score 0):

y не может иметь целый тип

```
y: double; //или single или real
```